# Java, format double as dollar value

Tags: java, jvm, jgrasp

I am writing a simple loan calculator for a class.  I am attempting to have the amounts return in dollar form.  I have found system.out.printf(); but cannot seem to make it work properly.

Here is the current code: (I am also aware it doesn't work correctly, will fix later)

```
public static void calculate() {

    annualInterest = (annualInterest * 0.01) / 12; //percentage to decimal then to month interest %
    term = term * 12;
    double payment = amtBorrowed * annualInterest;

    double temp = 1/(1 + annualInterest);
    temp = Math.pow(temp,term);
    temp = 1 - temp;

    payment = payment / temp;
    double Interest = amtBorrowed * annualInterest;
    double principal = payment - Interest;

    System.out.println("Your monthly payment is " + payment);
    System.out.println("          | Interest | principal");
    System.out.println("Month 1 :" +"   "+ Interest + " " + principal);
    for (int i = 2; i < term + 1; i ++){
        System.out.print("Month "+ i + " :");
        amtBorrowed = amtBorrowed - (Interest + principal);
        payment = amtBorrowed * annualInterest;
        temp = 1/(1 + annualInterest);
        temp = Math.pow(temp,term);
        temp = 1 - temp;
        payment = payment / temp;
        Interest = amtBorrowed * annualInterest;
        principal = payment - Interest;
        System.out.println("   " + Interest + "    " + principal);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Your monthly payment is 4432.061025275802
          | Interest | principal
Month 1 :   500.0 3932.0610252758024
Month 2 :   477.839694873621    3757.789681084494
Month 3 :   456.6615479938304    3591.242149217312
Month 4 :   436.4220295077747    3432.0761055985745
Month 5 :   417.079538832243    3279.9643981645363
Month 6 :   398.5943191472591    3134.594374430564
```

Comment: Why you should use double for currency http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/double-your-money-again.html

Comment: aren't I using a double? do you mean not use? Ill read the article thanks!

Comment: Someone commented on why you shouldn't use `double` but I happen to disagree.  Most investment banks use long or double not BigDecimal (esp in C++)

Answer (score 3):

Using printf instead

```
System.out.printf("Your monthly payment is $%.2f%n", payment);
```

This should print

```
Your monthly payment is $4432.06
```

Also

```
System.out.printf(" %8.2f %8.2f%n", Interest, principal);
```

Comment: Also why the 8 in %8.2? why not the first example?

Comment: @user2210274 The `8` pads out the number so your columns will line up. i.e. it has a minimum width of 8.  In the first example, you might not want lots of spaces between $ and the number.

Answer (score 1):

check if this helps 
`DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(doubleValue)`